# Rails I18n.l wants a yaml file for every time zone...but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization

I just added a field time_zone to my user model and filled it with UTC + 01:00 and, on a second try, with 'Bern' just to test things.

Before I set this time zone thing, calls in a view like l @date, :format => :short were no problem because it took the format from my {locale}.yml file. But now, after adding time_zone, rails is looking for a {time_zone}.yml file for date conversion formats.

I don't see the real sense behind this. I know that different countries display dates and times in a different way than others. But is creating a file for each time zone the right solution, especially when a lot of time zones will have the same display format? I don't think this is DRY.

However, I need to work with time zones because dates are wrong displayed. How can I keep the behaviour of working with {locale}.yml files and... just define a time zone which converts dates displayed to the right value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be creating the {time_zone}.yml files as links to the {locale}.yml files, so you only have to maintain one file instead of two (I'm assuming that the fields needed for {time_zone}.yml are present in {locale}.yml)

Comment: right, would be an option. but i'm still curious, when assigning a time zone and locale in console and calling I18n.l it works with the basic {locale}.yml and is not requesting a time_zone one